# How to set width according to parends in Flutter Widget

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

Material(
        elevation: 0,

```
      child:

        Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
            bottom: 10
          ),
          child: Stack(

            children: <Widget>[
              Positioned(
                left: 30,
                child: Container(

                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: 50
                  ),
                  height: 80,
                  color: Colors.black12,
                  child: Text("From : " + bills[index].fromDate.toString() + ""
                      "to : " + bills[index].toDate.toString()),
                ),
              ),
                  Container(
                        width: 80.0,
                        height: 80.0,
                        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.orange,
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                        ),
                ),
              Positioned(
                top: 20,
                left: 10,
                child: Text(bills[index].bill.toString() + bills[index].currency),
              ),


          ],

      ),
        ),
    );
```

In the above code, this widget below is a member of the stack and I could not set width according to the parents. usually, I suffer setting match_parent attribute in a flutter. 
I apply SizedBox.extend solution. the solution doesn't work for me.
                 Positioned(
                    left: 30,
                    child: Container(

```
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: 50
                  ),
                  height: 80,
                  color: Colors.black12,
                  child: Text("From : " + bills[index].fromDate.toString() + ""
                      "to : " + bills[index].toDate.toString()),
                ),
              ),
```

Please help me out. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
Positioned(
   left: 30,
   right: 0,
   child: Container(
      /* your widget */
   )
)
```